# How to bundle tinyMCE with Larave + Vite + Vue project

Tags: vue.js, tinymce, bundle, vite

The project is built with Laravel using Vite and Vue.
As I prefer not to use Tiny Cloud, I attempted to integrate TinyMCE into my application's bundle.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <textarea ref="editorRef"></textarea>
    </div>
</template>
  
<script lang="ts" setup>
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';
import 'tinymce/themes/silver/theme';
import 'tinymce/plugins/advlist/plugin';

const { modelValue = "", options = {} } = defineProps({ modelValue: String, options: Object });

interface Emit {
    (e: 'update:modelValue', value: String): void;
}
const emit = defineEmits<Emit>();

const editorRef = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
    tinymce.init({
        target: editorRef.value,
        plugins: 'advlist',
        toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | bullist numlist',
        setup: editor => {
            editor.on('init', () => {
                editor.setContent(modelValue);
            })
            editor.on('change', () => {
                emit("update:modelValue", editor.getContent());
            })
        },
        ...options,
    });
})
</script>
```

When I run the code, console error occurred.

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at model.js:1:1) icons.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at icons.js:1:1)`

In reality, it is sending a request for `model.js` and `icons.js`. I attempted to locate which part of the system is sending the request for them, but was unsuccessful in finding it.

I would appreciate it if someone let me know what issue is and how to bundle TinyMCE with my project.

Thanks!